# Make a jquery mobile checkbox not clickable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, checkbox

So i am using jquery mobile and i have a checkbox and label in a form like so :

```
<form class="myForm">
  <label><input checked name="myCheckBox" id="myCheckBox" onclick="return false;" onkeydown="return false;" type="checkbox">Checking</label>
</form>
```

Now comes my question: How can i make the checkbox readonly ? So the user can click on it but it wont change its state? I dont want to use the disabled option!

> NOTE: Before you mark it as a duplicate ive searched for answers and could
>   only find solutions using none jquerymobile checkboxes. They solved it
>   with: `onclick="return false"` which is not working... in jquerymobile you can test it
>   with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzsm1doq/). If you remove the external resources `onclick="return false"` is working.

Comment: *I dont want to use the disabled option!* Why? What you're trying to achieve is the exact purpose of that option.

Comment: I dont want to use it because it will be grayed out. Can i avoid that?

Comment: I see. I'll have a look.

Comment: It's does not appear to be easy to do -- even preventing the default `vclick` behavior fails to work (probably because the original checkbox is not part of the final widget). ezanker's solution should work, though.

Comment: Yea it does, thanks for beeing cool though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use disabled and then override the CSS that grays the checkbox:

```
.myForm .ui-checkbox.ui-state-disabled {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

jQM applies opacity to the DIV that surrounds the enhanced checkbox. This CSS resets the opacity to 1.

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mzsm1doq/1/)**